# How to read epubs stored in Google drive on mobile phone?

Tags: google-drive

Is there an ereader application that enables me to read my ebooks (in epub format) directly from my Google drive ?

Answer (score 1):

FBReader works for me on my android phone.

I would expect any app that can handle epubs would work.